# curl: works ONLY using "sudo" for Remote Server-1, and without "sudo" for Remote Server-2

Tags: linux-networking, curl

i am using curl in my local linux server to access my remote web service, and i found that both servers are reachable. But my issue is that Remote Server-1 is not accessible without "sudo" but my another server (Remote Server-2) is accessible without sudo.

```
OS: RHEL
Firewalld: Enabled -- 80,443 ports, https services allowed
Remote Server-1 --> Gives response with sudo
                --> Gives Error "curl: (56) Received HTTP code 503 from proxy after CONNECT"

Remote Server-2 --> works & gets response with/without "sudo"
```

i dont understand why my Remote server-1 is not accessible in user level, where the other server is accessible. Both of these servers are in same environment.

Please help.

Comment: Do you have a proxy configured to connect to these servers ? This proxy may be available only for users and not for root ? It may have an exception for your server 2 to not use the proxy.

Comment: Ohh yes.. that is right.. i have set up a proxy in the user which is blocking my other remoter server. i have removed that and now my Remote Server-1 is accessible without sudo.

Comment: thanks a lot Dom.. please provide answer, i will mark this question as "resolved"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you may check if there is a proxy between your client and your servers. It may be only defined for the user and not for root.
The proxy then reject your connections because of the configuration.

Comment: Thanks Dom.. Proxy is the problem that i fixed and now i am able to access servers without sudo.